# ¿Como juntar dos consultas de sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Actualmente tengo estas dos consultas:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS aprobadas, MONTH(fecha) AS mes, fecha FROM cotizaciones
 WHERE fecha >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH, '%Y-%m-%d') AND vb=1 GROUP BY mes ORDER BY fecha DESC

SELECT COUNT(*) AS rechazada, MONTH(fecha) AS mes, fecha FROM cotizaciones
 WHERE fecha >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH, '%Y-%m-%d') AND anulada=0 GROUP BY mes ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

La primera me muestra las cotizaciones "aprobadas" de los últimos dos meses:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la segunda query, muestra las cotizaciones rechazadas de los últimos 2 meses:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito saber como puedo unir las cotizaciones, donde puedo mostrar las cotizaciones aprobadas y rechazadas de los últimos dos meses, por ejemplo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que importa no son las fechas, sino los meses....es decir necesito me muestre unas filas de los últimos x meses las cotizaciones aprobadas y rechazadas en la query

Si alguien sabe algun ejemplo, se lo agradecería. Desde ya, gracias.

Comment: Algun ejemplo por ahí?

Comment: Pudiera ser que aporte uno, pero me sigue causando duda el tema de las fechas, una vez que conjuntes ambas columnas ¿cómo determinas que fechas dejar?

Comment: Lo que importa no son las fechas, sino los meses....es decir necesito me muestre unas filas de los últimos x meses las cotizaciones aprobadas y rechazadas en la query

Comment: ysi usas concat???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes intentar con `SUM` ya que si se cumple, agrega en 1 al contador de aprobadas (en otro caso no hace nada) y lo mismo con anulada:

```
SELECT SUM(vb = 1) AS aprobadas, SUM(anulada = 0) AS rechazada, MONTH(fecha) AS mes
FROM cotizaciones
WHERE fecha >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
  AND (vb = 1 OR anulada = 0)
GROUP BY mes
ORDER BY mes DESC;
```

Con un dataset como este:

| fecha | vb | anulada |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-16 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-03-17 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-18 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-04-20 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-26 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-05-26 | 0 | 1 |
| 2021-05-27 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-05-29 | 1 | 1 |

Obtienes:

| aprobadas | rechazada | mes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 0 | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 |

Answer (score -1):

Intenta juntar los dos select con la clausula UNION ALL en el caso de tu query quedaría algo asi:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS aprobadas, MONTH(fecha) AS mes, fecha FROM cotizaciones
 WHERE fecha >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH, '%Y-%m-%d') AND vb=1 GROUP BY mes ORDER BY fecha DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS rechazada, MONTH(fecha) AS mes FROM cotizaciones
 WHERE fecha >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH, '%Y-%m-%d') AND anulada=0 GROUP BY mes ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

Comment: Pero esta query le dará las filas de las rechazas por ejemplo debajo de las aprobadas no?

Comment: @BetaM, tienes razón, y eso no es lo que quiero, además no me funciona el order by fecha